# Installing QGIS 2.16 alongside QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, installation

I have QGIS 3.6 on my laptop. Is it possible to install QGIS 2.18 on the same laptop? Has someone this already done?

Comment: Should not be a problem ... i have 3 versions on my pc and it works like a charm ...

Comment: Which OS are you working on?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have all the QGIS versions you want on the same machine. I think lots of people have both the LTR version (or even older) for production work and a more recent version to access and test the new functionality

Comment: This works on Windows. For Linux systems, you have to put different versions in separate virtual boxes or similar.